# Is AngularJS Working in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing an AngularJS plugin for wordpress. I just can't see Angular working in Wordpress. Am I wrong or is there any specific way of integrating Angular to Wordpress. I enqueued all the required Angular files correctly and as it didn't workout, I then enqueued a normal JS file to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong. Even Angular didn't work, my normal JS file worked. Please give me an explanation.

---

Adding my code

plugin file enqueue scripts

```
wp_enqueue_script('angular', plugins_url('/libraries/angular_material/node_modules/angular/angular.js', __FILE__), array(''));

wp_enqueue_script('plugin-scripts', plugins_url('/js/plugin.js', __FILE__), array('angular'));
```

plugin.js file

```
var my_app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate']);

my_app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$mdDialog", function ($scope, $http, $window, $mdDialog) {

        $scope.test = function () {
            alert("OK");
        };

    }]);
```

front end markup PHP file

```
<div class="layout_parent" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-click="test();" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

</div>
```

---

Thank you very much all of you in advance.

Best Regards,
Nimantha Perera

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work. I have added numerous angular apps into wordpress.

Comment: To a Wordpress plugin??

Comment: Yes. Without more particulars of errors or conflicts nobody can really help you much

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I get no conflicts. No errors. I just added a simple alert function. Let me edit the question with the code.

Comment: Are scripts loading properly in page? Do you see button?

Comment: Thank you very much for you sir. It's really nice to see people like you. I get it sorted out. The problem is that I'm sending an empty array when I enqueue the angular.js which probably couldn't be a problem, however it did. When I remove the empty dependency array when I enqueue the angular.js file, it worked. Once again thank you very much sir. It's really kind of you. :-)

Comment: actually that's not an empty array...it's an array with one element that is an empty string....  `count(array('')) === 1`

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you very much for pointing it out... !!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little different approach how you can integrate AngularJS front-end with WordPress back-end via WP JSON API plugin.
http://studioraygun.co.uk/blog/web-development/angularjs-front-end-wordpress-back-end/

However, it seems that you are using this approach of Activating the WP-API plugin and Enqueuing the script directly.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'path/to/my/script', array( 'wp-api' ) );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/